# Using a 4th dimension to make Seifert surfaces isotopic?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds

Let $L$ be a link in three manifold $M^3$ and let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be two homeomorphic surfaces in $M$ with $L = \partial F_1 = \partial F_2$.  Suppose that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are not isotopic rel boundary in $M$.  Suppose that we have some 4-manifold $X^4$ with $\partial X = M$.

Is it possible for $F_1$ and $F_2$ to be isotopic rel boundary in $X$?

**Edit:** I just took a look at the paper of Livingston that Anthony mentioned and in it he takes an example of two such surfaces $F_1$ and $F_2$ in $S^3$ due to Trotter and are not isotopic in $S^3$, and shows that they are isotopic in $B^4$.  He suggests that there are simpler examples of this phenomenon, and I'd love to hear about those, but that answers this question.  In particular, Trotter's examples are surfaces with homeomorphic complements (which are handlebodies) - Trotter tells them apart by looking at the Seifert forms.

If so, and $M = S^3$ (or some homology sphere), are there examples of this phenomenon where the framings on the components of $L$ induced by $F_1$ and $F_2$ are different?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to construct $X$ such that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are isotopic, right? Also you need them to have same genus.

Comment: Section 6 of this paper of Livingston might be of interest: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029002727 for the case of $S^3=\partial D^4$.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee Thanks I added the genus comment.  I'm thinking of $X$ as given and wondering if there exist such $F_1, F_2$. Anthony's comment confirms that they always exist, so I am mainly interested in the second question about framings.

Comment: I didn't look at Livingston's paper, but I think that there are simple examples if you don't require the surfaces to be incompressible. Take a knot with a minimal genus Seifert surface (for example, the fiber of a fibered knot), and add a trivial handle to to get a surface $F_1$, and a knotted handle (lying inside a ball) to get a surface $F_2$. These surfaces will not be isotopic in the knot complement since their complements are not homeomorphic (unlike Trotter's example). Yet they are isotopic in $B^4$ by general position (the core of the 1-handles can be isotoped).

Comment: @IanAgol Oh sure thanks - that does the trick.

Comment: Do you want $L$ to be oriented and $F_1$ and $F_2$ to be orientable? Otherwise there are two Möbius bands bounding the unknot with different Euler numbers, and you can take the positive and negative Hopf link and the two annuli they bound (as oriented links).