# Are two slice surfaces with minimal genus isotopic?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, seifert-surfaces

For a link $L\subset S^3$ and two *Seifert surfaces* (edit: a better name would be slice surfaces as the comments below [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438878/are-two-slice-surfaces-with-minimal-genus-isotopic#comment1131877_438878) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438878/are-two-slice-surfaces-with-minimal-genus-isotopic#comment1131880_438878) point out) with minimal genus $S_1,S_2\subset B^4$, I have the following questions:

1. Is it true that the surfaces are isotopic?
2. And if the knots are algebraic?
3. I am interested in the Hopf link, so the surface is a cylinder, is it true if the surfaces have genus zero?

I know of the existence of the paper [Livingston - Surfaces bounding the unlink](https://doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1029002727) and [Using a 4th dimension to make Seifert surfaces isotopic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376600/using-a-4th-dimension-to-make-seifert-surfaces-isotopic)
but it answers a particular case and I hope that there are updates since 1980 (does not seem so from the citations).

Comment: Google "Kakimizu complex."

Comment: @MoisheKohan Despite the use of the term Seifert surface OP seems to be asking about slice surfaces, as they write $S_1, S_2 \subset B^4$.

Comment: OP: What do you mean to assume about $S_1, S_2$? Are these merely surfaces embedded in the 4-ball for which $\partial (B^4, S_i) = (S^3, L)$? (I would call these slice surfaces, in analogy to slice disks.) Or do you mean to assume that these start their life as Seifert surfaces $S_i \subset S^3$ for which you have pushed $S_i \setminus L$ into the interior of the 4-ball?

Comment: @mme: I see, I should have read beyond the title...

Comment: By the way, even if the question were about "usual" Seifert surfaces, I think that the downvote was a bit hasty. The answer is well-known to specialists, but I don't think that this alone makes the question unsuitable for MO.

Comment: Yes, I meant slice surfaces in the sense of @mme, sorry, I am not very familiar with the terminology. I am having in mind something like Milnor fibers of plane curve singularities, so the surfaces live in $B^4$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is very loaded and the question would almost require a survey...

Anyway, the answer to your questions is mostly no. Let $S \subset S^4$ be a 2-knot (i.e. an embedded 2-sphere), $p \in S$ a point, and remove a small ball around $p$. The complement of $S$ in the complement of the ball is a slice disc $D$ for the unknot, and the fundamental group of the complement of $D$ is isomorphic to the complement of the fundamental group of $S^4\setminus S$, which can be non-trivial. (It is possible that $D$ is trivial if and only if $S$ is, but I don't want to make the claim without having properly checked). So, any $2$-knot with non-cyclic fundamental group gives you a slice disc for the unknot which is not isotopic to the standard one.

You can plant the construction into any minimal-genus Seifert surface, and probably you get the same construction for any knot. (Perhaps using the Alexander polynomial is a good way to show that you get different things, without worrying too much about Seifert--van Kampen.)

Now, you might ask: what about slice surfaces whose complement has cyclic fundamental group? Then the answer depends on the category. For locally-flat slice discs, Freedman showed that they are topologically isotopic. There's a [nice preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.12774) of Conway, Piccirillo, and Powell where they treat higher-genus surfaces and they give a complete classification in terms of algebro-topological data (Blanchfield forms). In the smooth category, things get pretty weird: Kyle Hayden has examples of slice discs that are topologically isotopic but not smoothly isotopic (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13681)) and of pushed-in Seifert surfaces that stay non-isotopic in $B^4$ (note that these automatically have cyclic fundamental group).

Back on the subject of pushed-in Seifert surfaces, Hayden, Kim, M. Miller, Park, and Sundberg proved that they can be topologically non-isotopic and topologically isotopic but not smoothly isotopic (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.15283) and the Quanta Magazine [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/special-surfaces-remain-distinct-in-four-dimensions-20220616/) on their result).

Comment: This is a helpful overview!  A side note:  my understanding is that the Hayden-Kim-Miller-Park-Sundberg paper is not just about the smooth category:  they first give a counterexample in the topological category (where the obstruction comes from the intersection form on the double cover, which I'm assuming fits into the Conway-Piccirillo-Powell framework) and then they use it to get a counterexample in the smooth category that isn't a counterexample in the topological category.

Comment: (Before anyone gets confused, I should note that I'm the number theorist Alison Beth Miller who likes Seifert/Blanchfield pairings, not the low-dimensional topological Allison N. Miller who knows this subject better than I do, not to mention that I'm not Maggie Miller of the Hayden-Kim-Miller-Park-Sundberg collaboration.)

Comment: Thanks Alison, you're right. The last sentence is indeed incorrect. I'll fix it now.